# Where can i find an executable program once i have finished writing c# code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, silverlight

In visual basic class I learned where I could find the .exe file once the program was done and run at least once. Basically we could take the icon for the .exe file and place it on the desktop so that a user could just double click on the icon to run the program without needing to open the IDE or look at any code.

Where/how can i find this kind of file for c# code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using a web application project you'll use the .aspx file that is generated to access your silverlight application.

The "application" so to speak is actually a file ending in ".xap" that can be found in your web project's `ClientBin` directory.

The .xap file can also be found in the silvelright project's Bin

If you're wanting to install the silverlight application to a desktop you'll have to enable the ability to run the application "Out of Browser" and it'll have to be installed. [More information on Out of Browser apps...](http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/out-of-browser/)

Comment: This is pretty much what i need. Thanks!

Comment: Well the idea makes sense to me. However when i enable out of browser and i try to right click in order to install the application. The only two options i have are "silverlight" and "remove application". I don't have an option to actually install my appliaction.

Comment: "remove application" would indicate that you've already installed it

Comment: but i never installed it, i just ran it from my IDE. Do i actually need to put the application on a webpage and have the users install the application from that webpage?

Comment: yes. I don't know why it would say you've installed it if you haven't though.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the bin/Debug folder in the project. (or bin/Release if you're using the release build).

You can also go to your project settings, then to the build tab, and in the "Output" heading read/change the "Output Path" setting.  This will let you output the exe to some other location, or just see where it is currently outputting in the event that it has already been changed on your machine.

Comment: In the debug folder all i see are a bunch of folders with strange names and some other files.. but no .exe. Does it matter that this is a silverlight application?

Comment: @rage Did you "build" the application?  And yes, it most certainly matters that it's a silverlight application.  A silverlight application won't resolve to an executable, it will resolve to a class library or some other type of package that can be used by something like IIS.  (That'll be true for both C# and VB.)  If you have a console app you'll see the exe at that path.

Comment: I did build the application. I guess since it's a silverlight application i won't find a .exe file like you said. Perhaps i should ask this question elsewhere?

Comment: @rage What else do you plan to hear?  A silverlight app won't *ever* generate an exe; it's not just in some other location.  It will produce entirely different file types used in entirely different ways.  Not being a silverlight expert I don't know what those files are and how they're used.  If you want an executable that runs your code you'll need to have a console app with the code, rather than a silverlight app.

Comment: Ok i understand. I wrote a silverlight application that some biology people will use (the application creates a whole bunch of graphs they will use). I was wondering if there was some way they could use the program without having to install the IDE and all that. thanks for the help!